Let $G$ be a non-abelian finite group whose all non-linear irreducible characters are faithful. Is there a classification of these groups?
Let $G$ be a non-abelian finite group whose all non-linear irreducible characters are faithful. Is there some kind of a classification of these groups?
If $G$ is a finite non-abelian simple group, the above is certainly true. The symmetric groups $S_n$ also has the above property. I can see that for a group $G$ as above, if $N\neq \{1\}$ is a normal subgroup, then $[G,G]\leq N$. In other words, $G/N$ is abelian. The converse is also true, that is, if $G/N$ is abelian for all normal subgroups $\{1\} \neq N\leq G$, then all non-linear irreducible characters are faithful.
So in other words, I am looking for a classification of non-abelian finite groups whose non-trivial quotients are all abelian.
Thanks in advance for any kind of reference or help.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

A buzzword here is "just nonabelian". In general group is called just $X$ if it has property $X$ but all its proper quotients do not have property $X$. Therefore a group is just nonabelian if it is nonabelian but all its proper quotients are abelian.
Let $G$ be a finite just nonabelian group.
As discussed in the comments section, $G'$ is characteristically simple. If $G'$ is nonabelian then $G' \cong S^n$ for some nonabelian simple group $S$. The centralizer $C_G(G')$ does not contain $G'$, so it must be trivial, and therefore $G$ embeds in $\mathrm{Aut}(S^n) \cong \mathrm{Aut}(S) \wr S_n$. Thus $G$ is an extension by $G' \cong S^n$ of an abelian subgroup $A$ of $\mathrm{Out}(S^n) \cong \mathrm{Out}(S) \wr S_n$. Moreover $A$ acts transitively on the $n$ factors of $S$ in $G'$. I am not sure if one can say more -- perhaps.
If $G'$ is abelian then $G$ is metabelian, so $G$ is just (strictly) metabelian. These groups were classified by Newman in the references below. It makes a big difference whether $Z(G)$ is trivial or not. If $Z(G)$ is trivial, the first paper shows that $G \le \mathrm{AGL}_1(q)$ for some prime power $q$. If $Z(G)$ is nontrivial then $G' \le Z(G)$, so $G$ is a class-2 nilpotent group, and in fact a $p$-group for some $p$ with $Z(G)$ cyclic and $G' \cong C_p$. These groups are classified in the second paper. Examples include extraspecial $p$-groups and the modular $p$-group $C_{p^{n-1}} \rtimes C_p$.
Newman, M. F., On a class of metabelian groups, Proc. Lond. Math. Soc., III. Ser. 10, 354-364 (1960). ZBL0099.25202.
Newman, M. F., On a class of nilpotent groups, Proc. Lond. Math. Soc., III. Ser. 10, 365-375 (1960). ZBL0099.25203.

The solvable case is discussed in Isaacs' book, Lemma 12.3. See also this paper: https://www.emis.de/journals/AM/11-2/am1729.pdf

This a really good answer. Just one note for people like me who were confused for a second: $C_G(G')$ is the centralizer of a normal subgroup hence normal itself and since all nontrivial normal subgroups of $G$ have to contain $G'$ for the condition to hold this means $C_G(G')$ is trivial when $G'$ is nonabelian.
